# If a thrown exception is always a copy of the exception object, why isn't this copy constructor being invoked?

Tags: c++

Scott Meyers says:

> C++ specifies that an object thrown as an exception is always copied and the copying is performed by the object's copy constructor.

But in my code:

```
struct test
{
    test() { cout << "constructor is called" << endl; }
    test(const test&) { cout << "copy constructor is called" << endl; }
    ~test() { cout << "destructor is called" << endl; }
};

void fun()
{
    throw test();
}

int main()
{
    try { 
       fun();
    }
    catch (test& t1) { cout << "exception handler" << endl; }
}
```

I do not see the exception object's copy constructor being called.

If I change the `catch` to receive the exception object by value then it is, but according to Meyers's quote the exception object should have been copied even when it's received by reference.

**Why is the copy constructor is not called (even when exception handling is performed by reference)?**

Comment: The question is "which is wrong: Meyers or my compiler?" Don't close questions just because you don't understand them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meyers is correct that a copy is made, semantically:

> `[C++11: 12.2/1]:` **Temporaries of class type are created in various contexts**: binding a reference to a prvalue (8.5.3), returning a prvalue (6.6.3), a conversion that creates a prvalue (4.1, 5.2.9, 5.2.11, 5.4), **throwing an exception (15.1),** entering a handler (15.3), and in some initializations (8.5). [..]
>
> `[C++11: 15.1/4]:` The memory for **the temporary copy of the exception** being thrown is allocated in an unspecified way, except as noted in 3.7.3.1. The temporary persists as long as there is a handler being executed for that exception.

However, copies can be elided by clever compilers and they are allowed to do so regardless of side-effects.

> `[C++11: 12.8/31]:` **When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object**, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization. This elision of copy/move operations, called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - [..]
> - **when a temporary class object** that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) **would be copied/moved to a class object** with the same cv-unqualified type, **the copy/move operation can be omitted** by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move.
> - [..]

Comment: For 12.8/31 we're actually in the next case, "when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualiﬁed type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move". `test()` is the temporary, the exception object allocated in an unspecified way is the object to which it is being copy/moved, which happens also to be a temporary. We aren't in the case you highlighted, since the operand `test()` is not the name of an object.

Comment: @SteveJessop: True. Also I think the condition regarding scope fails because of the "function call indirection" (term made up by me).

Comment: @SteveJessop: Is the final case irrelevant because of the accept-by-ref?

Comment: The bit you highlighted is to allow copy elision in the case `void fun() { test foo; throw foo; }`. So the scope of `foo` is just the function `fun()`, which doesn't contain the innermost try-block. I don't know why it forbids copy-elision for `void fun() { try { test foo; throw foo; } catch (std::bad_alloc &) {}` and `void fun(test foo) { throw foo; }`, though, I can't quite see why anyone would want to rely on the side-effects of the copy in those cases.

Comment: Meh, I'm not going to think too hard about it. This answer is correct "enough". :)

Comment: um... yes, this exception-declaration doesn't declare an object, rather it declares a reference. If you caught by value and there was no copy elision at all, you'd get two copies: one from the throw-expression operand to the unspecified storage, and one from the unspecified storage to the object in the exception-declaration. So there's two clauses permitting two elisions. To me, the last clause basically says "as above, except that here the temporary *might* have been bound to a reference, but you can elide anyway provided it makes no difference other than ctor/dtor execution".

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, when an object is thrown as an exception, the copy to exception object may be elided, and if the conditions for copy elision are met or would be met, except that the source is a function parameter, but a compiler is not eliding it for some reasons, the compiler must attempt to use the move constructor even if the object is designated by an lvalue.